# $f:U\subset\Bbb{R}^{n}$ is $C^k$ and $f'(a)$ has rank $p$, exists an embedding

Tags: analysis, differential-topology, matrix-rank

Let $f:U\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^{m}$ be a function of class $C^{k\geq 1}$, where $U$ is an open  subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$. If $f'(a)$ has rank $p$ for some $a\in U$,  there exists an embedding (immersion that is homeomorphism into its image) $\phi:V\rightarrow U$ of class $C^\infty,$ where $V\subset\Bbb{R}^{p}$ such that $f\circ \phi:V\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^{m}$ is an embedding.

I have seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789436/if-f-a-subset-mathbbrm-to-mathbbrn-is-of-class-c1-and-in-a-in) question, and I did understand the intuition, but I'm having problems to write it down.

By a Lemma, since $\dim(\textrm{Im}(f'(a)))$, there exists a decomposition $\Bbb{R}^m=\Bbb{R}^p\bigoplus\Bbb{R}^{m-p}$ such that the projection $$\pi:\Bbb{R}^{m}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^{p},(x,y)\mapsto x$$
applies $\textrm{Im}(f'(a))$ isomorphically.

> **Question:** How do I construct the map $\phi$?

Maybe I can use this projection to define my $\phi$, but I don't know exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not needed anything much more substantial than what Llohann said in the post you link.

Take a complement $E$ of $\ker f'(a)$. If $\iota: E \to \mathbb{R}^n $ is the inclusion, then $f \circ \iota$ is an immersion near $a$. (We've just killed the kernel of $f'(a)$.) Locally, it is then an embedding. Now you just pick any isomorphism $\Psi: \mathbb{R}^p \to E$ and let $\phi = \iota \circ \Psi$, of course restricted to the necessary neighbourhood.

Answer (score 2):

By a proposition (LIMA, Curso de Análise, vol.2), since $f'(a)$ has rank $p$, there exists a neighbourhood $A$ where $f$ has constant rank $p$. Because $f'(a)$ has rank $p$, we also have that there is a subspace $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ $p$-dimensional such that $f'(a)\big|_E$ is injective and $\mathbb{R}^p\overset{\varphi}{\rightarrow} E$. If we define $V_1=\varphi^{-1}(A\cap E)$ and $\phi=(\varphi^{-1})\big|_{V_1}\rightarrow U$, we obtain an embedding of class $C^\infty$. As we consider $V_1\subset A$, where $f$ has rank $p$, it's possible to show that $f \circ \phi$ is an immersion and we can find an open subset $V\subset V_1$ such that $(f \circ \phi)\big|_V$ is an embedding of class $C^k$.

Comment: "(...) since $f'(a)$ has rank $p$, there exists a neighbourhood $A$ where $f$ has constant rank $p$." This is false. The simplest example is perhaps $f(x)=x^2$. $f'(0)$ has rank $0$ and $f$ does not have constant rank around $0$. This bogs down to rank not being continuous, but *lower semi-continuous*. What is true is that if $f'(a)$ has rank $p$, then there exists a neighbourhood around $a$ where $f$ has rank *greater than or equal to* $p$. In particular, if $f$ has full rank at $a$, then there exists a neighborhood around $a$ where it has full rank. Maybe this is the proposition you mention.

Comment: You're absolutely right. What the proposition actually garantees is that we can find an open set $A$ where $f$ has constant rank in each of its connected components. Even more, $A=\cup_p A_p$, where $A_p$ is the interior of the subset of $U$ where $f$ has rank $p$. What happens in the counterexample you've presented is that $f'(x)$ has rank $0$ only for $x=0$, so $A_0= \emptyset$.